# MYSQL: how can i select dates from this current day up to the next 2 months

Tags: mysql

i have to select from my homework dates from this time up to the next 2 months...
i'm doing an expiration database.. pls help me

Answer (score 0):

[Read and learn !](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from homework where homework_date between now() and now() + interval 2 month;
```

Comment: Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DATE' at line 1

Comment: @jzce - you have to change the column names to match your database.

Comment: Also, I left out an underscore the first time I posted it, but I fixed that 20 minutes before you posted your comment.